# SQL Server Table Locking

Tags: sql, transactions, locking, uniqueidentifier

I need to create a unique identifier for clients, I'm implementing this using a 9 digit Luhn (9th digit being the checkdigit), so I can validate its authenticity. The numbers I want to generate are random, so I create an 8 digit number and work out the check digit to go with it, that's all great.

My problem is that I need to check that it doesn't already exist in my client table. I have added an index to ensure duplicate values can't be inserted, but am looking for a steer on how to lock the table involved within the transaction I've created to ensure no concurrency issues arise, i.e. can't attempt to insert a duplicate.

Any suggestions on approach or recommendations welcome, I know this is probably a noddy question.

Comment: Use nolock  such that no transaction will effect each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you don't have direct control over which type of lock is used and when. You do have the ability, however, to place multiple statements within an explicitly defined transaction.

At the end of the transaction, you can check to see if there were errors in processing or if your data is in an invalid state. Then you would commit if everything is fine or rollback if not. But, beware of leaving transactions open! If you don't commit or rollback your transaction, the affected tables will remain locked and all transactions against those tables will be blocked until you either commit or rollback the transaction.

Here is an example that will hopefully be of help:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,Luhn INT
    ,UNIQUE(Luhn)
)

DECLARE @MaxTries INT = 10;
DECLARE @Try INT = 1;

DECLARE @Luhn INT; 
DECLARE @IsLuhnAvailable BIT = 0;

BEGIN TRAN;

WHILE @IsLuhnAvailable = 0 AND @Try <= @MaxTries 
BEGIN

    SET @Luhn = CHECKSUM(NEWID()); --dbo.GenerateLuhn()

    SET @IsLuhnAvailable = CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM @Table WHERE Luhn = @Luhn ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;

    SET @Try +=1;

END

IF @IsLuhnAvailable = 0 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Luhn could not be generated.'
    ROLLBACK;
END
ELSE
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @Table
    (
        Luhn
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @Luhn
    )
    PRINT 'New Luhn was generated: ' + CAST(@Luhn AS VARCHAR)
    COMMIT;
END

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks Brennan. I guess in my scenario if between the EXISTS and INSERT statements by coincidence, a duplicate value is attempted then at least I'll get an constraint violation error which I can then handle client side. So probably nothing to worry about too much in fact?

Comment: Either strategy, with or without an explicit transaction, would work. The reason I was wrapping the two statements in a transaction was to avoid the constraint violation error, causing the coincidental second transaction to wait on the first instead of processing concurrently.

Comment: Another pitfall when using explicitly defined transactions is the possibility of creating deadlocks. To avoid deadlocks, try to minimize the number of statements and try to access tables in a standard order.